# Write EXIF data after have added image to MediaStore

Tags: android, exif, android-contentresolver, mediastore, android-exifinterface

I just need to add some Exif metadata to a Jpeg saved to MediaStore (using Content Resolver)

Here how I save the image:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, now);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, now);

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = resolver.insert( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values );

    try( OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri) )
    {
        // Perform operations on "stream".
        bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream );
        stream.flush();
    } catch( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here how I try to add Exif metadata:

```
    private void writeExif( Uri uri, List<String> exifStr )
    {
        try
        {
            // THIS fails on file opening ( Read Failed: EBADF (Bad File Descriptor)
//            uri = MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(uri);       // UNUSEFULL
            ParcelFileDescriptor imageFd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface( imageFd.getFileDescriptor() );

            // THIS fails on file opening ( open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) )
//            String filename = getRealPathFromURI( uri );      // Extract full pathname from (deprecataed) MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA column
//            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface( filename );

            // THIS fails on saveAttributes ( write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor) )
//            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface( getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) );

            for( int i = 0; i < ExifAttributes.length; i++ )
            {
                String value = exifStr.get(i);
                if( value != null )
                    exif.setAttribute(ExifAttributes[i], value);
            }
            
            exif.saveAttributes();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In any way, I try to do it (check commented lines) I get some error (Bad File Descriptor or access denied)

The use of the path from 'MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA' is just a test and MUST not be used in the solution (I'm targeting API 29 and it is deprecated). But anyway, it does not work either.

Have anyone idea of how I can get rid of this?

Thanks

P.S. The image is correctly saved, just the writeExif() part fails.

Comment: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` you should open an output stream to begin with if you wanna write. Or not?

Comment: Further if you only tell that something fails we dont know why. Post error messages, exceptions and such.

Comment: @blackapps ExifInterface does not accept outputStream. It accept inputStream, pathname or FileDescriptor. It creates a temp file, opens an outputStream and copies the file internally. Since the error changes with the case, I wrote them in the comments: (Read Failed: EBADF (Bad File Descriptor) or Write Failed: EBADF (Bad File Descriptor))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved.
The problem was that the file was not syncronized on disk.

So, here how it works for saving the image:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, now);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, now);

ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values );

try( ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri,"w") )
{
    FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();

    try( OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fd) )
    {
        // Perform operations on "stream".
        mBitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream );
    }

    // Synch data with disk. It's mandatory to be able later to call writeExif
    fd.sync();    // <---- HERE THE SOLUTION

} catch( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And how I add Exif metadata:

```
private void writeExif( Uri uri, List<String> exifStr )
{
    try( ParcelFileDescriptor imagePfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw") )
    {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface( imagePfd.getFileDescriptor() );

        for( int i = 0; i < ExifAttributes.length; i++ )
        {
            String value = exifStr.get(i);
            if( value != null )
                exif.setAttribute(ExifAttributes[i], value);
        }
        
        exif.saveAttributes();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```